# How to set fixed width for tables in phpword (auto fit : fixed column width)

Tags: php, html, css, phpword

I'm using phpword version 0.12.0. I have a problem managing large contents writing inside cell. Even the cell have some fixed width, if the content is too large (in the case when there is no space between characters), cell layouts becomes broken. (please see the image)

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current version (0.13) I guess you should break the string yourself.
See: https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#table.

Comment: In that case we have a string and it can be splitted. What about cells with fixed width? Using pixels or twips for width, if we start typing the cell width changes automatically. Word has an option called 'Fixed Column Width'. PHPWord has a similar option?

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS:

```
td { overflow-x: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```